# How to check first 200 chekboxes , then next 200 and so on?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to use javascript or jquery to do the above ?

```
<a href=#>Check 1-200</a>
<a href=#>Check 201-401</a>
<a href=#>Check 402-602</a>

<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[1]' value='1'>
<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[2]' value='2'>
<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[3]' value='3'>
<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[4]' value='4'>
```

i tried the following code but it  doesnt check any boxes! How to fix it ?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
       var $cbs = $('input:checkbox[name="checkbox[]"]'),
           $links = $("a"); 

       $links.click(function() {
          var start = $links.index(this) * 200,
              end = start + 200;
          $cbs.slice(start,end).prop("checked",true);
       });
    });
```

Comment: What user can deal with 200 and 400 check boxes?  I'd rethink that UI.

Comment: Can you give the first 200 a `set1` class, and the next 200 `set2` class, so you only need to target a specific class of inputs each time?

Comment: This is an identical post with a solution already provided here at SO, here's the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329891/javascript-or-jquery-to-check-first-20-checkboxes-then-next-20-and-so-on. all you have done is changed the number of checkboxes from 20 to 200!

Comment: Check your checkbox selector: `alert($cbs.length)` = 0

Comment: @psylogic nice find - so the question is: "I found someone else's code, made a change and don't understand anything, please help"

Comment: The change between original and this is `name='checkbox[1]'` vs `name='checkbox[]'`

Comment: my checkboxe name has array number but in that example the checkbox has no array number! how to deal with checkboxes that has array number ?

Comment: What's with this array number?? name or id is just a string, I don't get it when I see names like that.

Comment: @Abhitalks although the question is not tagged as such, this is frequently used with asp.net-mvc to bind a list to the controller action.  Would be helpful if the OP stated why they changed the original answer (and referenced the original answer as a matter of courtesy)

Comment: Ahh thanks @freedomn-m. Let's close this as a dupe of the one you linked to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the working eg of first 3 and next 3 check boxes, but as suggestion please don't have these many check boxes, the user experience is very bad in this case.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
       var $cbs = $('input:checkbox'),
           $links = $("a"); 

       $links.click(function() {
          var start = $links.index(this) * 3,
              end = start + 3;
              $cbs.slice(start,end).prop("checked",true);
       });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href=#>Check 1-3</a>
<a href=#>Check 4-7</a>


<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[1]' value='1'>
<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[2]' value='2'>
<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[3]' value='3'>
<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[4]' value='4'>
<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[4]' value='5'>
<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[4]' value='6'>
<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[4]' value='7'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you generate all checkboxes using server side language. Simply inside the loop where you generate them, give them a common class name per every 200 checkboxes - like `part_200` then `part_400` etc.

Once you have that class, it will be easier for you to reference checkboxes in JS. You will be able to select all checkboxes where class name equals `part_200` or `part_400`.

I hope you get the idea. It's very easy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your jQuery selector: `input:checkbox[name="checkbox[]"]` that will return an empty list (no checkboxes is named exactly like that).
And you cannot do regexp with jQuery selector.
What I would do is to use a special class or attribute for each of the checkbox you want to select and query them this way.
In the below example I used `checkToCheck`.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   console.log("here");
   var $cbs = $('input:checkbox.checkToCheck'),
       $links = $("a"); 

   $links.click(function() {
     var start = $links.index(this) * 200,
         end = start + 200;
     $cbs.slice(start,end).prop("checked",true);
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href=#>Check 1-200</a>
<a href=#>Check 201-401</a>
<a href=#>Check 402-602</a>

<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[1]' class="checkToCheck" value='1'>
<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[2]' class="checkToCheck" value='2'>
<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[3]' class="checkToCheck" value='3'>
<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[4]' class="checkToCheck" value='4'>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has checkboxes defined as:

```
 <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[1]' value='1'>
```

The [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9330122/2181514) had them as

```
 <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='1'>
```

The selector:

```
$('input:checkbox[name="select[]"]')
```

will match where then *name* matches explicitly "select[]" but the name is now "select[1]"

Easiest option at this point is to use a different selector, eg put the checkboxes inside a div, eg:

```
<div id='selectboxes'>
     <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[1]' value='1'>
```

and use

```
$('div :checkbox')
```

---

Another option might be to give your checkboxes page numbers when they are generated, eg:

```
 <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[1]' value='1' data-page='1'>
```

then in your click handler:

```
 $(':checkbox[data-page="' + $links.index(this) + '"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectors `:gt(n)` and `:lt(n)` to get collection of checkboxes. So you just have to calculate indexes and construct a full selector.