# On button click, check n checkboxes of a form with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a button which will check n checkboxes, where `n` is defined as a data attribute in the button `data-num="2"`. I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329891/javascript-or-jquery-to-check-first-20-checkboxes-then-next-20-and-so-on) and I am trying to use jQuery solution but it doesn't work..

What am I missing? What I have done:

1. At first all inputs are unchecked.
2. On click of the button, I read its data attribute.
3. Then, I try to reach the input (type checkbox) not all of them but those that are under this button.
4. Check these inputs with `slice`

```js
var selectFirst = 0;
$('.selectFirstN').on('click', function() {
  selectFirst = $(this).data('num');
  console.log("Here selectFirstN = " + selectFirst);
  $(this).parent('.search-inputs').find('.checkboxfind').slice(0, selectFirst).prop("checked", true);


  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row mb-4 selectBtns">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-12 search-inputs">
    <div class="row justify-content-around">
      <div class="col">
        <p class="font-weight-bold mb-0">Title - 01</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <button class="btn btn-dark float-right selectFirstN" data-num="2">Select</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <label id="PO-04419_1" class="btn btn-block btnclick btn-light hideBoxInCheckbox text-left mb-3">
            <input type="checkbox" name="mesId" class="checkboxfind" value="1">           
            <span>PO-04419_1</span>
        </label>

    <label id="PO-04419_2" class="btn btn-block btnclick btn-light hideBoxInCheckbox text-left mb-3">
            <input type="checkbox" name="mesId" class="checkboxfind" value="2">           
            <span>PO-04419_2</span>
        </label>

    <label id="PO-04419_3" class="btn btn-block btnclick btn-light hideBoxInCheckbox text-left mb-3">
            <input type="checkbox" name="mesId" class="checkboxfind" value="3">           
            <span>PO-04419_3</span>
        </label>

    <label id="PO-04419_4" class="btn btn-block btnclick btn-light hideBoxInCheckbox text-left mb-3">
            <input type="checkbox" name="mesId" class="checkboxfind" value="4">           
            <span>PO-04419_4</span>
        </label>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row mb-4 selectBtns">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-12 search-inputs">
    <div class="row justify-content-around">
      <div class="col">
        <p class="font-weight-bold mb-0">Title - 02</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <button class="btn btn-dark float-right selectFirstN" data-num="3">Select</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <label id="PO-04419_1" class="btn btn-block btnclick btn-light hideBoxInCheckbox text-left mb-3">
            <input type="checkbox" name="mesId" class="checkboxfind" value="1">           
            <span>PO-04420_1</span>
        </label>

    <label id="PO-04419_2" class="btn btn-block btnclick btn-light hideBoxInCheckbox text-left mb-3">
            <input type="checkbox" name="mesId" class="checkboxfind" value="2">           
            <span>PO-04420_2</span>
        </label>

    <label id="PO-04420_3" class="btn btn-block btnclick btn-light hideBoxInCheckbox text-left mb-3">
            <input type="checkbox" name="mesId" class="checkboxfind" value="3">           
            <span>PO-04419_3</span>
        </label>

    <label id="PO-04420_4" class="btn btn-block btnclick btn-light hideBoxInCheckbox text-left mb-3">
            <input type="checkbox" name="mesId" class="checkboxfind" value="4">           
            <span>PO-04419_4</span>
        </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had an issue selecting the **parent**/**ancestor**

Use `parents` or `closest` instead of `parent`

[Check here](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)

```js
var selectFirst = 0;
$('.selectFirstN').on('click', function() {
  selectFirst = $(this).data('num');
  console.log("Here selectFirstN = " + selectFirst);
  $(this).parents('.search-inputs').find('.checkboxfind').slice(0, selectFirst).prop("checked", true);

  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row mb-4 selectBtns">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-12 search-inputs">
    <div class="row justify-content-around">
      <div class="col">
        <p class="font-weight-bold mb-0">Title - 01</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <button class="btn btn-dark float-right selectFirstN" data-num="2">Select</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <label id="PO-04419_1" class="btn btn-block btnclick btn-light hideBoxInCheckbox text-left mb-3">
            <input type="checkbox" name="mesId" class="checkboxfind" value="1">           
            <span>PO-04419_1</span>
        </label>

    <label id="PO-04419_2" class="btn btn-block btnclick btn-light hideBoxInCheckbox text-left mb-3">
            <input type="checkbox" name="mesId" class="checkboxfind" value="2">           
            <span>PO-04419_2</span>
        </label>

    <label id="PO-04419_3" class="btn btn-block btnclick btn-light hideBoxInCheckbox text-left mb-3">
            <input type="checkbox" name="mesId" class="checkboxfind" value="3">           
            <span>PO-04419_3</span>
        </label>

    <label id="PO-04419_4" class="btn btn-block btnclick btn-light hideBoxInCheckbox text-left mb-3">
            <input type="checkbox" name="mesId" class="checkboxfind" value="4">           
            <span>PO-04419_4</span>
        </label>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row mb-4 selectBtns">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-12 search-inputs">
    <div class="row justify-content-around">
      <div class="col">
        <p class="font-weight-bold mb-0">Title - 02</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <button class="btn btn-dark float-right selectFirstN" data-num="3">Select</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <label id="PO-04419_1" class="btn btn-block btnclick btn-light hideBoxInCheckbox text-left mb-3">
            <input type="checkbox" name="mesId" class="checkboxfind" value="1">           
            <span>PO-04420_1</span>
        </label>

    <label id="PO-04419_2" class="btn btn-block btnclick btn-light hideBoxInCheckbox text-left mb-3">
            <input type="checkbox" name="mesId" class="checkboxfind" value="2">           
            <span>PO-04420_2</span>
        </label>

    <label id="PO-04420_3" class="btn btn-block btnclick btn-light hideBoxInCheckbox text-left mb-3">
            <input type="checkbox" name="mesId" class="checkboxfind" value="3">           
            <span>PO-04419_3</span>
        </label>

    <label id="PO-04420_4" class="btn btn-block btnclick btn-light hideBoxInCheckbox text-left mb-3">
            <input type="checkbox" name="mesId" class="checkboxfind" value="4">           
            <span>PO-04419_4</span>
        </label>
  </div>
</div>
```